# Which virtual machine image for installing FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation

The [FreeBSD download page](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html) offers links to Virtual Machine Images, including [one link for AMD64](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/VM-IMAGES/10.1-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/).

That AMD64 folder offers three files:

- FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64.raw.xz
- FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64.vhd.xz
- FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64.vmdk.xz

What are each of these for, what's the difference between them? I cannot find documentation.

In particular I'm wonder if any will work for use in [Parallels 10](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/).

Comment: I installed the freebsd amd64 images without any hitch at all under VirtualBox in El Capitan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## UPDATE

The [documentation](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/virtualization/#virtualization-guest-parallelsdesktop) has step by step instructions for running FreeBSD as a Guest on Parallels Desktop for macOS® 10.4.6 or higher.

The previous now-outmoded Answer remains below for history.

---

## `.xz`

First, the last extension `.xz` is a lossless data compression program and file format which incorporates the LZMA/LZMA2 compression algorithms, say [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz). [Developed](http://tukaani.org/xz/format.html) by [The Tukaani Project](http://tukaani.org/).

For use on Mac OS X, Apple’s [Archive Utility.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_Utility) cannot handle this format (as of Yosemite). The XZ project page suggests using the [XZ Utils](http://macpkg.sourceforge.net) library and command-line tool. You can obtain unarchiving apps on the Apple App Store. [The Unarchiver app](https://macappsto.re/us/Hx3wz.m) worked for me for the FreeBSD .xz installer files.

## `.raw`, `.vhd`, `.vmdk`

Second to the last extension is one of three types of virtual hard drive file formats.

- `.raw`
  I do not know.
- `.vhd`
  [`Virtual Hard Disk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format)) format. Developed by [Connectix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectix) (now Microsoft). As of 2005, this format’s spec is available to other parties. Can be used with [Parallels Desktop 10](http://betanews.com/2014/08/27/parallels-desktop-10-officially-released-promises-improved-performance-adds-new-disk-space-wizard/).
- `.vmdk`
  [`Virtual Machine Disk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMDK) format. Developed by [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware). Can be used with [Parallels Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac), and [Oracle VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox).

## No Go on Parallels 10

While Parallels 10.2 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 can open and convert both .vhd and .vmdk formats to its own format, when I tried each FreeBSD installer I got an error saying:

> Failed to convert this virtual hard disk.
>
> The guest OS installed on the disk cannot be identified. You can still convert this disk using the prl_convert utility with the --allow-no-os option."

Comment: I would mention *Hyper-V* for `.vhd` and *VMware Workstation/ESXi* as a tool compatible to `.vmdk` files. The `.raw` file is just (as the name implies) a block-wise representation of the underlying disk. May be used e.g. with qemu (KVM), Virtual Box, ...

Comment: I can't tell if this is answering the question or is a comment that you can't get it to work. If the latter, I can report there are many FreeBSD users happily using it on Macs and OSX for years.

Comment: @Basil Bourque   I get the same error in Parallels 14  use `prl_convert` only get a `hdd` file.  But I don't know how to use that. Do you solve it

Answer (score 1):

> What are each of these for, what's the difference between them? I
> cannot find documentation.

While [Basil Bourque](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56752/basil-bourque)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194545/254839) is quite informative and to the point. Below is the excerpt from their README file on FreeBSD download page. I hope it helps with `raw` format.

> ```
> FreeBSD virtual machine disk images are available in various formats
> for several hypervisors.
>
> Disk image formats and the supported hypervisors are:
>
> - vhd: VirtualPC, Hyper-V, Xen, VirtualBox
> - vmdk: VMWare qcow2: Qemu, KVM
> ```
>
> > ```
> > - raw: bhyve, other hypervisors that support unformatted raw disk image
> > ```
>
> *Source: [FreeBSD.org](https://www.freebsd.org/where/)*